# Returning two values with different types by a function in c

Tags: c, structure

can we return two values by function in c?

for example: here i am trying to build a function that return if there is a majority element or not, if there is one we return (true, x) wheras x the majority elemnt, else, we return (false, 0)

````
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

// Fonction qui verifie si il y a un element majoritaire ou pas 
//dans une liste en utilisant un algorithme recursive



int nbr_occ(int A[], int n, int x)
{
    int c=0, i;
    
    for(i=0;i<n; i++)
    {
        if (A[i]==x) c++;
    }
    return c;
}
(_Bool , int) majoritaire (int A[], int i, int j)
{
    bool rx, ry;
    int x, y;
    if(i=j) return (true, A[i]);
       (rx, x) = majoritaire (A, i, (i+j)/2) ;
       (ry, y) = majoritaire (A, (i+j)/2 + 1, j);
        
       if (rx=false && ry=false)
       return (false, 0)    ;
       if (rx= true && ry=true)
       {
           if( x=y ) return (vrai, x)
           else if ( nbr_occ(x) > (i-j)/2 ) return (true, x);
           else if ( nbr_occ(y) > (i-j)/2 ) return (true, y);
           else return (false, 0);
       }
       else if(rx=true)
       {
           if ( nbr_occ(x) > (i-j)/2) return (true, x);
           else return (false, 0);
       }
       else if (ry=true)
       {
           if( nbr_occ(x) > (i-j)/2 ) return (true, y);
           else return ( false,0);
       }
}```
````

Comment: Do you know how `struct` works? You can return a `struct` containing a `_Bool` and an `int`.

Comment: you could define an int-value that stands for "no-majority", e.g. `#define NO_MAJORITY INT_MIN`; or you could define a `struct` comprising two members.

Comment: @StephanLechner but anyway i still should return two values by one function

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya can you show a example how to return two values by one function using a struct, please!

Answer (score 0):

See the following code illustrating how to return a `struct`. Please adapt this for your purposes then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    _Bool hasMajority;
    int majority;
} majorityStruct;

majorityStruct myFunc(int a, int b) {
    // just for demonstration:
    majorityStruct result;
    if (a == b) {
        result.hasMajority = false;
        result.majority = 0;
    } else {
        result.hasMajority = true;
        result.majority = a-b;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    majorityStruct f = myFunc(20, 10);
    printf("%d:%d\n", f.hasMajority, f.majority);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom is to return one of the values normally (usually the one that indicates success/failure) and store the other one at an address provided by the caller, i.e. into a variable passed by reference.

```
_Bool majoritaire (int A[], int i, int j, int *result) {
    // ...
    if (has_majority) {
        *result = m;
        return true;
    } else {
        *result = 0; // or omit this, and document that 
                     // the result is only valid when true is returned
        return false;
    }
}

void other_function(void) {
    int r;
    if (majoritaire(A, i, j, &r)) {
        printf("There is a majority and it is %d\n", r);
    } else {
        printf("No majority\n");
    }
}
```

In my experience, this is more common than the `struct` approach when only two values need to be returned.